# How to Integrate SCORM Package in React Application with react-scorm-provider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scorm, scorm1.2, lms

I'm attempting to integrate a SCORM package into a React application using the react-scorm-provider library. My goal is to display a SCORM package in an iframe and then access SCORM data such as student name, status, and tracking information. However, I'm struggling to establish a connection with the SCORM API to retrieve this data.

Here is the structure of my code:
Parent Component (App.js):

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import ScormProvider from "react-scorm-provider";
 import Scorm from "components/Scorm";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ScormProvider version="1.2" debug={true}>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Quiz</h1>
        <hr />
        <Scorm />
      </div>
    </ScormProvider>
  );
}
```

Child Component (Scorm.jsx):

```
import React from "react";
import { withScorm } from "react-scorm-provider";

const Scorm = (props) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <iframe
          src="https://louuu03.github.io/Scorm_Example/story.html"
          height="600px"
          width="900px"
          title="Scorm Package URL"
        />
        <br />
        <button onClick={() => { console.log(props); }}>
          Click Me
        </button>
      </div>
    );
}

export default withScorm()(Scorm);
```

this is i am seeing in my browser' console:

[image]

Comment: Are you importing and playing the SCORM package in a SCORM player? For example SCORM Cloud?

Comment: No I am not this is all I have written in my react application. 
I saw this code sandbox example -
 https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/affectionate-jones-trorv3?file=%2Fsrc%2FQuestion.js
where someone hosted the scorm package and it is working properly in code sandbox but not in my local machine. i am using the exact url.

Comment: If you look at the content of `public/index.html` you will see the most bare minimalist implementation of a SCORM RTE (Run Time Environment) which is essentially providing a mock of a SCORM Player to allow that small snippet of code to work and allow the library to function.

Answer (score 1):

The react-scorm-provider library provides the client-side SCORM API functionality. Like all SCORM courses, you are still required to launch the course within an LMS environment, which provides the server-side SCORM API. If you don't have an LMS, you can test your course in SCORM Cloud for free.

Comment: How can we launch the course within LMS environment locally in our react application?

Comment: That is a non-trivial thing to do, based on the nature of SCORM and how browsers handle CORS. See https://scorm.com/scorm-cross-domain/ for more.